# Malloc error in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, retain

Right now in my application there is a producer that outputs an array of data; the output from that producer is bound (using the "Bindings" in the XIB file) to a Table View in my window.  The producer spits out data, and it shows up in the window, all is well.

Except that I need to modify the data being shown.  The producer is a third-party app, so I can't modify it directly, so I need to create a filter object that sits between the two.

The object I created looks like this:

```
@interface testFilter: NSObject {
id output;
}
-(void)setInput:(id)s;
@end
```

I changed the binding so that the output from the producer goes to my input:

```
[myFilter bind:@"input" toObject:producer withKeyPath:@"output" options:0];
```

and my implementation looks like this:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    output = nil;
    return self;
}

- (void)setInput:(id)newInput
{
    int nEntries = (int)[newInput count];
    id copiedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    for (id entry in newInput)
    {
        id copiedEntry = [entry mutableCopy];
        // blah blah make some changes to copiedEntry
        [copiedArray addObject:copiedEntry];
        [copiedEntry release];   // I'm done with it, copiedArray added his own retain
    }
    [self setValue:copiedArray forKey:@"output"];

    [copiedArray release];   // I'm done with it, setValue/output added a retain
}
```

But this is crashing with the error:

> "malloc: *** error for object 0x108e00870: pointer being freed was not allocated"

...until I remove the `[copiedArray release]` line.

Am I wrong in thinking that I should be sending `[copiedArray release]`?

What else can I check / what is the recommended way to debug problems like this?

Comment: The recommended way is to use ARC and never explicitly call release at all.

Comment: Incidentally, `[newInput valueForKey:@"mutableCopy"]` will do the same thing as most of that `for` loop, which is to create an array (assuming `newInput` is an array, since you didn't declare its type) of mutable copies of the input objects. You'll still need a `for` loop, but that loop will do nothing but make the changes that you commented out.

Comment: @PeterHosey, will `-valueForKey:` compensate for the fact that `-mutableCopy` returns a retained object, or will that leak the copied entries?

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon: Good question. I don't know, but my guess would be no. (And if not, you could hack around it with another `valueForKey:`, this time getting `autorelease`. That said, using KVC with `mutableCopy` is pretty hacky to start with, and doing the same with `autorelease` is even moreso.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
id copiedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
```

This will create an autoreleased object. You shouldn't release autoreleased objects.

Either remove your release call, or change that line to this:

```
id copiedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
```

That being said, consider using [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

---

From [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

> **You own any object you create**
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with `alloc`,
>   `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` (for example, `alloc`, `newObject`, or
>   `mutableCopy`).
>
> **You can take ownership of an object using retain**
>
> A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the
>   method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the
>   object to its invoker. You use `retain` in two situations: (1) In the
>   implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take
>   ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2)
>   To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some
>   other operation.
>
> **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
>
> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a `release`
>   message or an `autorelease` message. In Cocoa terminology,
>   relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred
>   to as “releasing” an object.
>
> **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**
>
> This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated